# Boost Unit Test compilation fail throught Eclipse

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, eclipse-cdt

I want to compile following line of code through Eclipse but during built time i will get Error which i can not understand.. Is any one have a solution to solve it.

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>


#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_AUTO_TEST_MAIN
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE First_TestSuite

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( First_TEst )
 {

BOOST_CHECK(2 == 2);


    }
```

---

Error

> 12:55:13 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project
>   NewProject **** Info: Internal Builder is used for build g++
>   "-IC:\boost_1_52_0\boost_1_52_0" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0
>   -o "src\NewProject.o" "..\src\NewProject.cpp"  g++ -o NewProject.exe "src\NewProject.o"  src\NewProject.o: In function
>   `ZN10First_TEst11test_methodEv':
>   C:\Users\sam\workspace1\NewProject\Debug/../src/NewProject.cpp:19:
>   undefined reference to`
>   boost::unit_test::unit_test_log_t::set_checkpoint(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring, unsigned int, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring)'
>   C:\Users\sam\workspace1\NewProject\Debug/../src/NewProject.cpp:19:
>   undefined reference to
>   `boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_impl(boost::test_tools::predicate_result
>   const&, boost::unit_test::lazy_ostream const&,
>   boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, unsigned int,
>   boost::test_tools::tt_detail::tool_level,
>   boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_type, unsigned int, ...)'
>   src\NewProject.o: In function`
>   _static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
>   C:\Users\sam\workspace1\NewProject\Debug/../src/NewProject.cpp:16:
>   undefined reference to
>   `boost::unit_test::ut_detail::auto_test_unit_registrar::auto_test_unit_registrar(boost::unit_test::test_case*,
>   unsigned long)' src\NewProject.o: In function`
>   ZN5boost9unit_test15unit_test_log_tC1Ev':
>   C:/boost_1_52_0/boost_1_52_0/boost/test/unit_test_log.hpp:131:
>   undefined reference to `vtable for boost::unit_test::unit_test_log_t'
>   src\NewProject.o: In function`
>   ZN5boost9unit_test14make_test_caseERKNS0_9callback0INS0_9ut_detail6unusedEEENS0_13basic_cstringIKcEE':
>   C:/boost_1_52_0/boost_1_52_0/boost/test/unit_test_suite_impl.hpp:255:
>   undefined reference to
>   `boost::unit_test::ut_detail::normalize_test_case_name(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)'
>   C:/boost_1_52_0/boost_1_52_0/boost/test/unit_test_suite_impl.hpp:255:
>   undefined reference to`
>   boost::unit_test::test_case::test_case(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring,
>   boost::unit_test::callback0
>   const&)' src\NewProject.o: In function
>   `ZN5boost9unit_test15unit_test_log_tD1Ev':
>   C:/boost_1_52_0/boost_1_52_0/boost/test/unit_test_log.hpp:93:
>   undefined reference to`vtable for boost::unit_test::unit_test_log_t'
>   c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text.startup+0xa7):
>   undefined reference to `WinMain@16' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status
>
> 12:55:24 Build Finished (took 11s.567ms)

Answer (score 6):

seems that you forgot to add `-lboost_unit_test_framework-mt`
or whatever that library is named in windows system

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but what do you mean i forget to add -lboost_unit_test_framework-mt. where should i add it ??? could you please explain more because i am quit unfamiliar with C++ and Eclipse..

Comment: In Eclipse: Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Libraries tab -> Add button... Here is a [picture](http://goo.gl/pvEbX).

Comment: Just in case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117572/what-every-c-developer-should-know-about-linking?rq=1

Comment: Hi Thank you so much. i check all my Boost Directory but i did not find anything such as boost_unit_test_framework-mt.. please consider that i use hear file not compiled version. Can you please let under which directory i can find it. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If you want to only use the header variant, you should include the following

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE First_TestSuite
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
```

instead of your

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

And you only need the `#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE First_TestSuite` with the header only variant.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Single Header Variant of the UTF` from Boost.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/usage-variants/single-header-variant.html